# The book "Accelerated C++: Practical Programming by Example". End-of-file indictation misunderstanding

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream

The authors explain how to write a function which reads grades from standard input and puts them into a vector, but they do it in a confusing fashion. I'll put here an excerpt that confuses me:

> ... we don’t quite know when to stop. We can keep reading grades until we can no longer do so, but at that point we have a problem.
>
> There are two reasons why we might no longer be able to read a grade:
> We might have reached end-of-file, or we might have encountered something that is not a grade.
>
> In the first case, our caller will think that we have reached end-of-file. This thought will be true but misleading, because the end-of-file indication will have occurred only after we have successfully read all the data.
> Normally, an end-of-file indication means that an input attempt failed.
>
> In the second case, when we have encountered something that isn’t a grade, the library will mark the input stream as being in failure state, which means that future input requests will fail, just as if we had reached end-of-file.
>
> Therefore, our caller will think that something is wrong with the input data, when the only problem was that the last homework grade was followed by something that was not a homework grade.
>
> In either case, then, we would like to pretend that we never saw whatever followed the last homework grade.
>
> Such pretense turns out to be easy:
> If we reached end-of-file, there was no additional input to read; if we encountered something that wasn’t a grade, the library will have left it unread for the next input attempt.
>
> Therefore, all we must do is tell the library to disregard whatever condition caused the input attempt to fail, be it end-of- file or invalid input.
> We do so by calling `in.clear()` to reset the error state inside `in`, which tells the library that input can continue despite the failure.

I understand the part that tells that there are two reasons that make us unable to read data.

The first is the end-of-file, and the second is a piece of data that cannot be treated as a double.

And now, the authors try to go deeper into these two cases which confuses me. They say that we need to read all the data to get the end-of-file indication, and right after that, they say that any fail of getting input, leads to the end-of-file indication. It seems like the authors contradict themselves.

I put a bit more text here, so you have some context, and I need a more clear and understandable rewrite.

Comment: Something tells me this author was paid by word count.

Comment: Assuming the file is a `std::ifstream` (or a related class), then there are separate flags for end-of-file and other error states; the: `.eof()` and `.fail()` member functions can be used to check these. If `.fail()` returns `true` but `.eof()` returns `false`, then we can call `.clear()` to reset the stream to a "good" state and continue trying to read more data, from just after the point where the read failure happened.

Comment: The author doesn't mention either of them. He just calls `.clear()` without mentioning the ability to distinguish these two states.

Comment: Related to eof: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: The problem is just with understanding the words that the authors put into this excerpt, I'm not confused with using eof as it isn't used here explicitly.

Comment: The quoted text is badly written, and it sounds like the mechanism it's describing is badly designed. Unless there's a good reason to continue, I recommend finding another source of information.

Comment: What is this terrible book? So we can avoid it?

Comment: There's an assumption somewhere in this text that the program doesn't care whether there was invalid data or it reached the end of a valid file. But that's not the only way to do it, and it certainly is possible (even normal) for a program to handle those cases differently.

Comment: I put the title of the book into the title of the question, it is [Accelerated C++: Practical Programming by Example](https://www.amazon.com/Accelerated-C-Practical-Programming-Example/dp/020170353X/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1XGMP4GG2H3OO&keywords=accelerated+c%2B%2B&qid=1705456912&sprefix=accelerated+c%2B%2Caps%2C310&sr=8-1).

Comment: If you can suggest a good resource to learn C++, it can be great. It seems that many of respected sources for beginners in C++ are not particularly readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of confusion, here, is (most likely) with the phrase, *"just as if we had reached end-of-file"* (although, I agree, the whole paragraph is somewhat mumbly and meandering).

When using a [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) object (or one from a derived/related class), there are a number of conditions that can cause an attempted read operation to fail: one is that the end-of-file has been reached (in which case we're done); another is that bad input data – i.e. a character or characters that cannot be interpreted as a `double` (say) – is encountered in the file stream.

In the latter case, the read will fail and a flag (typically the `failbit` or `badbit` members) will be set. In the former case, the `eofbit` member will (also) be set.

We can call the [`.fail()` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) of the stream object to test if **either** of those situations has occurred, and we can call the [`.eof()` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) to test *specifically* if the end-of-file has been reached.

If `fail()` returns `true` but `eof()` returns `false`, then we can call the [`.clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) function to reset/clear the flags, after which we can continue reading (or *trying* to read) more data. We can continue this read/test/clear cycle until we get an *actual* EOF.

Answer (score 1):

> The authors tell that we need to read all the data to get the end-of-file indication and right after they tell that any fail of getting input leads to the end-of-file indication.

This sounds like a contradiction, but a failure does not actually lead to an end-of-file indication.

An input stream has several flags to keep track of its state.  One

- `eofbit` is set if a read was been attempted after then end of the input (file) was reached.
- `failbit` is set if an extraction failed because the data wasn't in the expected format.
- `badbit` is set if there has been an unrecoverable error, e.g., if it wasn't able to open the file at all.

(In the documentation, you may also see `goodbit`, but the stream's state doesn't have a but for that.  The state is good if the other three bits are all clear.)

Without the code snippet being described by the text, we don't know which method they authors are using to test the stream's state.  There's a useful [table at the bottom of this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good) that shows the possible combinations of the stream's state bits and the various ways to check them.

Depending on how it's written, a loop may terminate if there's a problem extracting a grade *or* if it has reached the end of the file.  By calling the `clear` method and attempting another read, it becomes possible to distinguish between the causes.

Comment: The authors check the initial state of the input stream by using it in a test `if (input_stream) {...}`, read all data from it by using the while loop `while (input_stream >> vector)` and finish with clearing the state of the the input stream `input_stream.clear()`. That's all. Not even a word about different bits related to the input stream that can be set in different situations.